# Need to display records join results as well as remaing qty without join

Tags: mysql

i have 3 tables. need to display records join results as well as remaing qty without join

tblBookhead

---

BookHeadId, bookname, bookauthor,...

tblBookDetail

---

BookHeaddetailId,BookHeadId,Qty

tblBookorder

---

orderid,BookHeaddetailId , orderqty

```
select * from tblBookhead bh inner join tblBookDetail bd on
bh.BookHeadId=bd.BookHeadId inner join tblBookorder br on
br.BookHeaddetailId=db.BookHeaddetailId where BookHeadId=1;
```

this will retrun good results no problem.
but now if qty is 10 for BookHeadId=1 and orderqty=5 then result need to display remaing 5 qty without join (my expectation is null values for remaining qty in tblBookorder )

my expected result would be:

---

```
BookHeadId, bookname, bookauthor,... BookHeaddetailId,BookHeadId,Qty,orderid,BookHeaddetailId , orderqty
1           1           john         1                  1       10    1       1                  5
1           1           john         1                  1       10    null     null              null
```

Comment: Some data sample and expected results would help us.

Comment: 'without join' OK. Don't use an RDBMS.

Comment: shall i need to do in java @Strawberry

Comment: An expected result with no corresponding data set is about as useful as a chocolate teapot. If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.